# Puerto Rico locale is wrong concerning the time format

Tags: gnome, format, language-support, time, locale

The regional settings for the locale of Puerto Rico shows its time in 24 hour format no matter WHAT I DO... Its time format should be the 12 hour format.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: This is a [long-standing bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1130501). In the latest comment at that bug report I asked about links to some authoritative sources which prove that the a.m./p.m. format is in use. It would be good if you could help move this issue forward by commenting on the bug report.

Comment: Will have to look in to it... it is ridicules that they mention they need proof of the standards use in the country to even care to look in to it. Incredible that this has just been the norm for so long. It reminds me of the old good old days of help files filled with » bla bla bla And I am not kidding of that! Gnome has always had this type of polish in one way or an other... is it to big for them?

Answer (score 0):

[image: languagesupport2]

If you want to change the format in Date and Time , you must install dconf-tool . From terminal do

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Find it through Dash by writing **dconf** open it and goto Com > Canonical > Indicator > Datetime and from there you can change the format.

[image: Date-time]

In order to show AM/PM you have to change the clock format field in the digital clock settings to `%I:%M %p`

Logout and Login for changes to take effect.

Comment: Options seem to not be available on my end with my version of Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.03.

Comment: I have: com > canonical > unity » basically am screwed Gnome developers have other things to care for... HIG Hitler! They keep on removing features... sad really.